# How to write unit tests for three.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, three.js, webgl

Essentially, what I'm asking is, is there a way to write unit tests for my JavaScript files for three.js library?

I have a 3D viewer that houses a camera, renderer, loader, etc... How do I write tests for something like that? Is there something out there that I can read for that? Is it even possible?

Comment: it is possible but it depends on exactly what you are thinking of, the three.js project comes with a [whole bunch of unit tests](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/test/unit) for itself so have a look at those to see how the three.js community does it

Comment: you can do stuff in javascript with three.js objects and then test that certain properties are as expected, `Object3D.position.equals(expectedPosition)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to unit test webgl/threejs in headless way. This does not need any image comparison etc.

https://github.com/AmitTeli/webgl-three-test

Approach taken:

1. Move all the **global variables** like **scene**, **renderer** and **camera** to *index.html*
2. Initialize them on loading of the page. e.g. in this reactjs example, they are initialized in *componentDidMount()* of the root component. Other functions can use this context. (You can check this by running **`yarn start`**)
3. While doing the unit testing, initialize them in *setupTest.js*. We will need additional dev dependencies of headless webgl - **gl** and **canvas**
4. With this setup now we can run the test in say *App.test.js* (You can check this by running **`yarn test`**)

Answer (score 0):

You can either test properties of the expected state or use headless browser like chromium to render expected and actual images. If you search for testing WebGL, you will find examples of the latter